# Cannot move csv file from one directory to other

Tags: java, file, archive

I am trying to archive a csv file after reading its content and storing it in the database. I am doing it as

```
String filename = file.getName();
File destiantion = new File(getAttribute(ST_ARCHIVE_FOLDER) + "/"+ filename);
boolean fileArchived = file.renameTo(destiantion);
```

where file = "D:\Users\400220260.INDCORP\Desktop\ParameterMargin20141009.csv"
and destination = "D:\Users\400220260.INDCORP\Desktop\Archive\ParameterMargin20141009.csv"

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Let us see some code

Comment: I forgot to close the FileReader in my File Object. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your File objects, but now you have to copy the old file to your new location. Just a rename on the file won't do what you want. This can be done like this:

```
public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
   destFile.createNewFile();
   FileChannel source = null;
   FileChannel destination = null;

   try {
      source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
      destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
      destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
   }
   finally {
      if(source != null) {
         source.close();
      }
      if(destination != null) {
         destination.close();
      }
   }
}
```

What would be even easier is using the copyFile method of FileUtils from Apache Commons IO, but therefore you have to add that library in your project:

```
FileUtils.copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile)
```

Comment: I have to move the file it is working fine but it is copying the file from one location to another

Comment: You can delete the first file using file.delete()

Answer (score 0):

As it stated in [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29):

```
The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another.
```

You could use [Files.copy(InputStream in, Path target, CopyOption... options)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) from `java.nio.file` to achieve this.